# How do I beat the ghosts with the mirrors?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

I just found a Toad in the Haunted Towers tree, then I get blocked by 3 female ghosts with mirrors. They spin around and eventually one peeks from behind the mirror and you can strobulb them, but after you start vacuuming them up, one of the other ghosts will hit you.

They hit you so early and for so much damage this isn't enough to beat them. So what exactly do I do against these three? If I flash one and wait, all three disappear again, so I don't see a way to catch more than one off guard at once.

Comment: I'm also having trouble defeating the three sisters because if you miss with the strobulb while they are circling, they all charge at you and you can't escape, so you lose 20hp. Meaning if you miss 5 times, you are dead! I have tried the mission 20 times now, each with the gold dog bone to revive me. When I do get hold of them and I try the method where you go towards the ghost you are capturing, I get dragged and lose 5hp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing I was missing in the fight with The Three Sisters is that while vacuuming **you dodge much faster by following the ghost**, allowing me to dodge the attacks. Here's several useful tips:

- Wait for a Sister to put down her mirror (which one does it is random) then quickly strobe them and start vacuuming.
- Dodge toward the ghost you're pulling to avoid the other ghosts, then pull away to change up your A button attack. Repeat as necessary.
- Strobulb the birds that spawn on occasion for some extra hearts between  attacks.
- Defeating a ghost gives you a heart.
- Defeat the orange, small Sister first as she has the least HP. It's much easier to dodge with one ghost down.

Comment: Good answer. I got them to drag me to one side, then I pulled back, then when the others were about to attack, stop pulling and get dragged over to the other side.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, and if you do it right, you will defeat all thee female ghosts. The three ghosts should be circling around you. They will not hurt you unless you make a move, but they will not let you go from their circle. Look at the three ghost and there should be one that looks out from behind their mirror after a couple seconds. Flash the one that looks out from behind the mirror, turn on the vacuum, begin to suck up the ghost, but don't pull back to charge the vacuum up yet. Let her drag you away from the other ghost, but don't let her drag you around too much, or more than you need to be. When you get a good distance away from the other(s), than charge up the vacuum. Keep a close eye on the remaining ghosts too, because they will come up behind you while you are focused on your ghost. When another ghost comes up behind you, let the one you are vacuuming drag you away and finish vacuuming it up. It's the same deal with the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a little problem at the beginning, but I managed to make it at the first try. If you have a longer A meter than a single one area to be filled up, you should only fill up one and the use your charge attack. If you see one of the three sisters attacking you, (that's their name as a group) the you can jump using the b button. This will erase the progress on the a meter, soo you will have to fill it up from the beginning. But only use that in an emergency, otherwise you should just pull towards the ghost that is in link with your vacuum, and start charging it when the other sisters are at a safe distance.

Answer (score -2):

Charge the strobobulb and hope to hit all three with the blast.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work at all